# How do I find the location of Python module sources?

Tags: python, module

How do I learn where the source file for a given Python module is installed? Is the method different on Windows than on Linux?

I'm trying to look for the source of the `datetime` module in particular, but I'm interested in a more general answer as well.

Answer (score 461, accepted):

For a pure python module you can find the source by looking at `themodule.__file__`.
The datetime module, however, is written in C, and therefore `datetime.__file__` points to a .so file (there is no `datetime.__file__` on Windows), and therefore, you can't see the source.

If you download a python source tarball and extract it, the modules' code can be found in the **Modules** subdirectory.

For example, if you want to find the datetime code for python 2.6, you can look at

```
Python-2.6/Modules/datetimemodule.c
```

You can also find the latest version of this file on github on the web at
https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/_datetimemodule.c

Comment: If you edit your answer to indicate that datetime.__file__ points to a .so on Linux & Mac OS X (though on Windows the datetime module object has no __file__ attribute), I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Actually on Windows (at least on the version I'm using), datetime just doesn't have a __file__ attribute.

Comment: Works great for self-installed modules.

Answer (score 271):

Running `python -v` from the command line should tell you what is being imported and from where.  This works for me on Windows and Mac OS X.

```
C:\>python -v
# installing zipimport hook
import zipimport # builtin
# installed zipimport hook
# C:\Python24\lib\site.pyc has bad mtime
import site # from C:\Python24\lib\site.py
# wrote C:\Python24\lib\site.pyc
# C:\Python24\lib\os.pyc has bad mtime
import os # from C:\Python24\lib\os.py
# wrote C:\Python24\lib\os.pyc
import nt # builtin
# C:\Python24\lib\ntpath.pyc has bad mtime
...
```

I'm not sure what those bad mtime's are on my install!

Comment: Cool! You can also type in your own specific import statement after it opens up in interactive mode to see where the specific lib comes from.

Comment: Where are `built-in` modules?

Comment: For MacOS users type `python3 -v`. You'll get the command results.

Answer (score 153):

I realize this answer is 4 years late, but the existing answers are misleading people.

The right way to do this is never `__file__`, or trying to walk through `sys.path` and search for yourself, etc. (unless you need to be backward compatible beyond 2.1).

It's the [`inspect`](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html) module—in particular, `getfile` or `getsourcefile`.

Unless you want to learn and implement the rules (which are documented, but painful, for CPython 2.x, and not documented at all for other implementations, or 3.x) for mapping `.pyc` to `.py` files; dealing with .zip archives, eggs, and module packages; trying different ways to get the path to `.so`/`.pyd` files that don't support `__file__`; figuring out what Jython/IronPython/PyPy do; etc. In which case, go for it.

Meanwhile, every Python version's source from 2.0+ is available online at `http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/X.Y/` (e.g., [2.7](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/) or [3.3](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.3/)). So, once you discover that `inspect.getfile(datetime)` is a `.so` or `.pyd` file like `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/datetime.so`, you can look it up inside the Modules directory. Strictly speaking, there's no way to be sure of which file defines which module, but nearly all of them are either `foo.c` or `foomodule.c`, so it shouldn't be hard to guess that [datetimemodule.c](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Modules/datetimemodule.c) is what you want.

Comment: Why is the is `__file__` not applicable for non-builtins? I understand where crawling sys.path can be painful (especially without knowing about meta_path), but is your concern about namespacing between `__file__` definitions and binaries?

Comment: I do this in 2.7.8 on datetime and just get a TypeError for both getfile and getsourcefile. Personally I have multiple versions of python installed and I need to know WHICH version of datetimemodule.c it's pointed at, because right now I know it's not pointed at the one it should be pointed at given the interpreter version that's running...

Comment: @mmitchell: If you're getting a TypeError from inspect.getfile(datetime), assuming datetime is actually the module and not something else you've assigned to the same name, I'm pretty sure that means you made a custom build to statically link in datetime to the interpreter instead of making it a loadable module. But there could be other reasons I haven't thought of. You need to ask a new question, and give a lot more info to reproduce this.

Comment: @mmitchell: Meanwhile, there's no way to find out which version of datetimemodule.c it's pointing at, because it's not pointing at datetimemodule.c, it's pointing at a compiled module built from that C file; the C file may not exist on your system, may have been edited since you compiled it, whatever.

Comment: @tristan: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking, but maybe this will answer it: Whenever `__file__` works, `inspect.getfile` works; there is no situation where guessing whether to use `__file__` will be better than just using the inspect module.

Comment: IIRC, when I wrote that, I think I was commenting on the fact that you're telling people to always avoid simply just using `__file__` or doing a bit of looking.

Comment: Yeah I know how compilation works, I was going with the ".c" for consistency with your answer. ;) I wasn't expecting a full solution to my problem either, just pointing out that your answer isn't working. I tested on a clean, vanilla install of 2.7.8 and got the error so it's nothing to do with custom stuff -- it just doesn't work on Windows.

Comment: @mmitchell: You're right, Windows sucks, at least for Python 2.x. As far as I can tell from looking under the hood, the information just isn't accessible at all. In 3.4 it's simple to find the file that would be imported by "import foo" (assuming it's actually a file, as opposed to, say, a member of a zip archive), which is almost always right (unless you, say, edited sys.path after the import), but in 2.7 that doesn't exist, and faking it is tough and not very robust.

Comment: @mmitchell: One thing that _should_ work, but I don't want to code it. :) The HANDLE to the DLL is stored inside the object at the C API level, and you can ask Win32 for paths and handles of DLLs, so with ctypes.pythonapi and pywin32, this should be doable. (It looks like .pyd files inside .zip archives are loaded by unpacking them to a temp location, so that's what you presumably get for anything but a straightforward import; not sure how useful it is, but...)

Answer (score 136):

If you're using pip to install your modules, just `pip show $module` the location is returned.

Comment: (I think `$module` was meant as a placeholder variable, not literally what one would type. E.g., `m=numpy; pip show $m` ...etc, for any `m`)

Comment: this should be marked as the most accurate answer for the question asked.

Comment: Actually, this method is not reliable if you have multiple pythons installed, because the `pip` that is executed from the shell may not be the same one called within python.

Instead, you should do `python -m pip show $module`. See [umesh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269795/how-do-i-find-the-location-of-python-module-sources/61095592#61095592).

Answer (score 82):

The `sys.path` list contains the list of directories which will be searched for modules at runtime:

```
python -v
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/local/lib/python25.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python2.5', ... ]
```

Comment: ```python -c 'import sys; print "\n".join(sys.path)'``` will let you view it without having to drop into interactive python.

Comment: Python 3: `python -c 'import sys; print("\n".join(sys.path))'`

Answer (score 55):

from the standard library try [imp.find_module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html#imp.find_module)

```
>>> import imp
>>> imp.find_module('fontTools')
(None, 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\FontTools\\fontTools', ('', '', 5))
>>> imp.find_module('datetime')
(None, 'datetime', ('', '', 6))
```

Comment: This is fantastic. I `apt-get remove`'d DataDog and could still import it. This helped me find where the files were (so I could delete them) when the other solutions didn't help.

Comment: for python3.x,  the `imp` package is deprecated  (since version 3.4) in favor of `importlib` (since 3.1) https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/imp.html

Comment: Now you need to use it in this way for python3. `import importlib` then `importlib.util.find_spec('fontTools')`

Comment: This is the answer. If you run python interactive session when a virtual environment is activated you can get details for both the modules in the VE and in the underlying python installation, unlike `python -m pip show xxx` for example, which appears only to show pip-installed modules. Confirm that `imp` is deprecated and "slated for removal in Python 3.12"

Answer (score 48):

`datetime` is a builtin module, so there is no (Python) source file.

For modules coming from `.py` (or `.pyc`) files, you can use `mymodule.__file__`, e.g.

```
> import random
> random.__file__
'C:\\Python25\\lib\\random.pyc'
```

Answer (score 14):

Here's a one-liner to get the filename for a module, suitable for shell aliasing:

```
echo 'import sys; t=__import__(sys.argv[1],fromlist=[\".\"]); print(t.__file__)'  | python -
```

Set up as an alias:

```
alias getpmpath="echo 'import sys; t=__import__(sys.argv[1],fromlist=[\".\"]); print(t.__file__)'  | python - "
```

To use:

```
$ getpmpath twisted
/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/twisted/__init__.pyc
$ getpmpath twisted.web
/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/twisted/web/__init__.pyc
```

Comment: The first version is wrong, too many backslashes. From a shell script, this works for me: `echo 'import sys; t=__import__(sys.argv[1],fromlist=["."]); print(t.__file__)'  | python - "$@"`

Answer (score 13):

In the python interpreter you could import the particular module and then type help(module). This gives details such as Name, File, Module Docs, Description et al.

Ex:

```
import os

help(os)


Help on module os:

NAME

os - OS routines for Mac, NT, or Posix depending on what system we're on.

FILE

/usr/lib/python2.6/os.py

MODULE DOCS

http://docs.python.org/library/os

DESCRIPTION

This exports:

- all functions from posix, nt, os2, or ce, e.g. unlink, stat, etc.

- os.path is one of the modules posixpath, or ntpath

- os.name is 'posix', 'nt', 'os2', 'ce' or 'riscos'
```

et al

Comment: This gave me a full path to the module file while other answers only gave relative paths. Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

On windows you can find the location of the python module as shown below:i.e find rest_framework module
[image]

Answer (score 11):

New in Python 3.2, you can now use e.g. `code_info()` from the dis module:
http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/3.2.html#dis

Answer (score 10):

Check out this [nifty "cdp" command](http://chris-lamb.co.uk/2010/04/22/locating-source-any-python-module/) to cd to the directory containing the source for the indicated Python module:

```
cdp () {
  cd "$(python -c "import os.path as _, ${1}; \
    print _.dirname(_.realpath(${1}.__file__[:-1]))"
  )"
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It's just what I was looking for. Odd enough they wouldn't include something of the kind into the python distro.

Answer (score 9):

Another way to check if you have multiple python versions installed, from the terminal.

`$ python3 -m pip show pyperclip`

Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-

`$ python -m pip show pyperclip`

Location: /Users/umeshvuyyuru/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages

Answer (score 9):

Just updating the answer in case anyone needs it now, I'm at Python 3.9 and using Pip to manage packages. Just use `pip show`, e.g.:

```sh
pip show numpy
```

It will give you all the details with the location of where pip is storing all your other packages.

Answer (score 5):

On Ubuntu 12.04, for example numpy package for python2, can be found at:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy
```

Of course, this is not generic answer

Answer (score 1):

Not all python modules are written in python. Datetime happens to be one of them that is not, and (on linux) is datetime.so.

You would have to download the source code to the python standard library to get at it.

Comment: Daryl: You misparsed Jim's answer, "Datetime happens to be one of the python modules not written in python".

Answer (score 1):

For those who prefer a GUI solution: if you're using a gui such as Spyder (part of the Anaconda installation) you can just right-click the module name (such as "csv" in "import csv") and select "go to definition" - this will open the file, but also on the top you can see the exact file location ("C:....csv.py")

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using interpreter then you can run the code below:

```
import site
print (site.getsitepackages())
```

Output:

```
['C:\\Users\\<your username>\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37', 'C:\\Users\\<your username>\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages']
```

The second element in Array will be your package location. In this case:

```
C:\Users\<your username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages
```

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32784452/7697796).

With utilizing `grep` and `awk` tools.
I find this works in the bash shell.

`pip show <any-installed-package> | grep Location | awk -F': ' '{print $2}'`

The idea is to filter the module path in the result.

```
$pip show pygments
Name: Pygments
Version: 2.16.1
Summary: Pygments is a syntax highlighting package written in Python.
Home-page: None
Author: None
Author-email: Georg Brandl <georg@python.org>
License: BSD-2-Clause
Location: $USER/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages
Requires:
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run this on pyCharm or other editor as per your wish

```
import module_name

print(module_name)
```

This will display the location of your module.

Answer (score 0):

In an IDE like Spyder, import the module and then run the module individually. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cXpx.png)

Comment: Import and print the `str()` of the model is a more accurate description of what you are doing in the screenshot, plus the IDE seems irrelevant for this solution

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please do not post code using images. Images are hard to read, cannot be searched, and are not viewable to some readers. Instead, please include any relevant code directly in the body of your answer.

Answer (score -1):

as written above
in python just use     help(module)
ie

import fractions

help(fractions)

if your module, in the example fractions, is installed then it will tell you location and info about it, if its not installed it says module not available

if its not available it doesn't come by default with python in which case you can check where you found it for download info