# how to get module location

Tags: python

when i import module using

```
import module_name
```

is it possible to see where in my hard disk is that module located?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/269795/how-do-i-find-the-location-of-python-module-sources

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is worth mentioning that packages have `__file__` attribute which points to `__init__.py`, they also have [`__path__`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#packages-in-multiple-directories) which points to the package directory. So you can use `hasattr(module_name, '__path__') and module_name.__path__[0] or module_name.__file__`.

Example (in REPL):

```
import socket, SOAPpy # SOAPpy is a package
socket.__file__
# .../python2.5/socket.pyc
socket.__path__
# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__path__'
SOAPpy.__file__
# .../2.5/site-packages/SOAPpy/__init__.pyc
SOAPpy.__path__
# ['.../2.5/site-packages/SOAPpy']
```

Comment: Do you have evidence? I just tried it on a package of my own, `__file__` is there (`package/__init__.pyc`), as it should be, seeing as the "package" import is just a module called `__init__`. (`package.__path__ == ['package']`)

Comment: what about functions? can there location be also determined (well the other option seems to be to just check path of the module from which it is being imported and hope that there is not mangling in between.

Comment: @Bunny you can use inspect as @Nedec suggested.

Answer (score 3):

Try: `module_name.__file__`.

If you want to 'inspect' an object, use: [inspect](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
import module_name
module_name.__file__
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use module's **file** attribute to find the location.

`import sys
print sys.__file__`