# Where are all the Python Modules in C (like "math" and "time") located?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wish to see the code of the modules in C of python, but it isn't in "Lib," which has every module. Where are these modules? I know that this question has been repeatedly asked, but that was before version 3.7.3.

I have Python 3.7.3, and I have checked most of the Python Folder that has the program itself.

Comment: I think you are referring to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11385576/where-do-i-find-the-python-standard-library-code

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for `Modules/` files https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/master/Modules