# How to locate a python package

Tags: python

I want to manually uninstall a python package, so it would not be accessible using `import`.
I cannot locate the package in my system.
When I use this [advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/269806/1082727) (run `python -v`), I have next output:

```
# /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/declarative/clsregistry.pyc matches /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/declarative/clsregistry.py
import sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.clsregistry # precompiled from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/declarative/clsregistry.pyc
# myfile.pyc matches myfile.py
import myfile # precompiled from myfile.pyc
```

myfile is a part of the package I want to uninstall.

How can I locate it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I find the location of Python module sources?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/269795/how-do-i-find-the-location-of-python-module-sources)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To print a module's location:

```
import myfile
myfile.__file__
```