# Python modules are different between IDE's

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, pythonxy, wing-ide

I am developing algorithms in python and mostly use IPython notebook, but when ever I need to debug I usually use Wing IDE. I'm currently having a strange problem. In the notebook, I do have a method from the matplotlib package (subplot2grid) but in Wing, I do not have this method.

most of my packages were installed with the installation of pythonXY. still i do not understand why wing is using a different matplotlib from IPython, and how something like that had happend in the first place (I dont think I installed matplotlib again beside from the pythonXY automatic installation).

What is going on here?

Comment: issue `print(sys.path)` from both Wing and IPython, examine the differences

Comment: Is there any other? like maybe seeing explicitly where matplotlib is coming from in both envr? or checking the version?

Comment: [How do I find the location of Python module sources?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/269795/how-do-i-find-the-location-of-python-module-sources)

Comment: Did you setup your interpreters correctly?

Comment: Thanks JOHN, i'll look at that. Games, I dont know..

Answer (score 1):

Wing looks for 'python' on the path or if none tries to find Python on your path or (on Windows) in the registry.  Look at sys.executable in the IPython notebook and set Python Executable in Wing's Project Properties (from the Project menu) to that full path.  Then the debugger should use the right Python.

Note that you'll need to restart the integrated Python Shell in Wing from its Options menu before that change takes effect there (Wing doesn't just automatically restart that, in case you have data or state there that you don't want to lose).