# Where are python modules stored?

Tags: python, module

I'm new to this and wondering, where's all the code for the modules and packages and stuff that you can import located on my computer.

Can anyone give me a short lesson and help me out?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/269795/how-do-i-find-the-location-of-python-module-sources

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose you want to know the location of `xyz` module. You do this on the interpreter

```
>>> import xyx
>>> xyz.__file__
```

You'll get the location of the `pyc` file from where your module is being imported.

You can also simply do

```
>>> xyz
```

to get the module name *and* the location of the module.

To know about **all** the possible locations from where the modules are imported, use [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.path):

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
```

This will give you the list of the locations where Python searches for a module when you do `import`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    sys._file_
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_file_'

Comment: Double-Underscore around file. You've put single.