# goslate package installation issue with Anaconda on windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, goslate

I am trying to install goslate package on anaconda 
`pip install goslate`

I am getting following traceback error, which shows following lines:

```
[Anaconda3] C:\Users\hyper>pip install goslate Collecting goslate
  Using cached goslate-1.5.0.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\hyper\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-wvbatk7b\goslate\
setup.py", line 30, in <module>
        long_description=read('README.rst'),
      File "C:\Users\hyper\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-wvbatk7b\goslate\
setup.py", line 17, in read
        return open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), fname)).read()
      File "C:\Users\hyper\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\encoding
s\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
        return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 2090:
 character maps to <undefined>

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\hyper\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-wvbatk7b\goslate`
```

Is there some other way to install goslate on windows. My python version is 3.5

Comment: I've opened [an issue for this](https://bitbucket.org/zhuoqiang/goslate/issues/6/unicodedecodeerror) on the repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue. I downloaded the goslate.py file and copied it in the \python35\lib directory. That worked for the 3.5 version. I didn't check if it would work for Anaconda. To find out where to copy the goslate.py file you can check this post: [How do I find the location of Python module sources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269795/how-do-i-find-the-location-of-python-module-sources)

Hopefully it will also work for you.

Comment: I tried with the zip file of the precompiled version and installed the setup in anaconda command prompt. It worked.