# Catch invalid month/day in "time data does not match format"

Tags: python, datetime

I'm converting a date string using the following (not the full code, just the relevant bit):

```
str_format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
datetime.strptime('2015-13-23 13:43:23', str_format)
```

This throws a "time data does not match format" because the month is wrong (13 is not a valid month).

I was wondering if it was possible to have it raise an exception on the month (or day) being invalid *instead* of the format not matching because of the invalid date? The following clearly shows that datetime can determine that:

```
>>> print datetime(2015, 13, 23)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: month must be in 1..12
```

Comment: The most common way to get the error is to swap the month and day, since US and European customs are opposite, so the error as is makes sense.

Comment: Why are you passing in the 13th month?

Comment: Not sure if it's the proper way, but may be you can raise an exception from and exception block

Comment: @NotAnAmbiTurner I think that's the point - perhaps someone fat-fingered the month, or as Mark pointed out they're used to a different format and put something like `2015-13-08`

Comment: @NotAnAmbiTurner, Wayne's right, I'm trying to handle a situation where someone inputs an invalid month/day (such as the 13th month), and to alert them to that instead of the "does not match format". The string _does_ match the format, it's just that the month is wrong, which isn't clear by the exception it ends up giving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always parse the text and then use it to construct a datetime yourself - or pre-validate it if that suits you:

```
from datetime import datetime

def to_datetime(date_string):
    year = int(date_string[0:4])
    month = int(date_string[5:7])
    day = int(date_string[8:10])

    return datetime(year, month, day)

print(to_datetime('2015-13-23 13:42:13'))
```

Throws:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 11, in <module>
    print(to_datetime('2015-13-23 13:42:13'))
  File "test.py", line 9, in to_datetime
    return datetime(year, month, day)
ValueError: month must be in 1..12
```

If you want to know how `datetime` does it - Use the Source, Luke!

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.__file__
'/usr/lib/python3.5/datetime.py'
```

Open that file and you'll find:

```
def _check_date_fields(year, month, day):
    year = _check_int_field(year)
    month = _check_int_field(month)
    day = _check_int_field(day)
    if not MINYEAR <= year <= MAXYEAR:
        raise ValueError('year must be in %d..%d' % (MINYEAR, MAXYEAR), year)
    if not 1 <= month <= 12:
        raise ValueError('month must be in 1..12', month)
    dim = _days_in_month(year, month)
    if not 1 <= day <= dim:
        raise ValueError('day must be in 1..%d' % dim, day)
    return year, month, day
```

Comment: should the day slice be `date_string[8:10]`?

Comment: @NotAnAmbiTurner ah, you're right. Apparently `int` disregards trailing spaces, though :)

Comment: @WayneWerner: It's (a little) more work than I was expecting, but this certainly covers it! I tried to look up the datetime.py file, but [apparently](http://stackoverflow.com/a/269825/4739755) I'll have to go fetch a tarball to get to it on Windows :-/

Comment: Oh interesting. You can also go find the source on [GitHub](https://github.com/python/cpython/find/master)

Answer (score 0):

I feel like there are two ways to approach this:

**Way 1**

```
str_format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

try:
    datetime.strptime('2015-13-23 13:43:23', str_format)
except ValueError:
    raise ValueError("Something went wrong")
```

The downside to this is that it's not constrained to *only* situations where the month or day are wrong, as your question initially asked.

**Way 2**

```
import calendar

str_format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
datetime_str = '2015-13-23 13:43:23'
year = int(datetime_str[0:4])
month = int(datetime_str[5:7])
day = int(datetime_str[8:10])
cal = calendar.Calendar(6)

if not 1 <= month <= 12:
    raise ValueError("wrong month")
else:
    days_list = list(cal.itermonthdays(year, month))
    if day not in days_list:
        raise ValueError("invalid day")
```

**If you want to use the generator without converting to a list**

```
....

if not 1 <= month <= 12:
    raise ValueError("wrong month")

days_gen = cal.itermonthdays(year, month)

for gen_day in days_gen:
    if gen_day == day:
        break
else:
    raise ValueError("wrong day")
```

Comment: Better specify `Exception Type` rather than Watch for all exceptions