# How do I find the location of Python module sources while I can not import it?

Tags: python, module, python-import

The answer in [How do I find the location of Python module sources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269795/how-do-i-find-the-location-of-python-module-sources) says just import it and print its `__file__`. But my question is that I cannot import a library `cv2` while it returns `ImportError: libcudart.so.7.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`, so I cannot get its `__file__` too. I want to find where does Python import this library so that I can check what is wrong with the library.

Comment: Try `import imp`, `imp.find_module('cv2')`.

Comment: @acw1668 It works! Now you can answer and I accept...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
import imp
imp.find_module('cv2')
```