# Using psycopg2 or other python module within Visual Code

Tags: python, psycopg2

I am using Visual Code and wanted to script some Python code that connects to a database. `Psycopg2` seems to be the perfect library for just that. So I had in my `settings.json` file:

```
{
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
    "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [
    "c:/OSGeo4W64/apps/python27",
    "C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/Python27/Lib/site-packages/psycopg2"
    ],
    "python.pythonPath": "C:/OSGeo4W64/bin/python.exe"

}
```

I still get the error

> 'no module named psycopg2'

on the first line in my code: `import psycopg2`.

Comment: Potentially silly question: you have installed `psycopg2`, right? `pip install psycopg2` for example

Answer (score 0):

Or psycopg2 is install but not in the right place you can check where it is with this method :

[How do I find the location of Python module sources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269795/how-do-i-find-the-location-of-python-module-sources)

or as have said bernie you don't have `psycopg2`you can check this way:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/588390/how-do-i-check-whether-a-module-is-installed-or-not-in-python

in this case in your terminal do : `pip install psycopg2`or if you use anaconda `conda install -c anaconda psycopg2=2.7.1`