# Why is Mozilla Deepspeech using Tensorflow 0.11 when I have 0.12 installed?

Tags: tensorflow, mozilla-deepspeech

I use Anaconda3 with python 3.6 and use pip install tensorflow deepspeech.

When I run the following command I get errors:

deepspeech --model models/output_graph.pb --alphabet models/alphabet.txt --audio voice.wav

```
Loading model from file models/output_graph.pb
TensorFlow: v1.11.0-9-g97d851f04e
DeepSpeech: unknown
Warning: reading entire model file into memory. Transform model file into an mmapped graph to reduce heap usage.
2018-12-26 18:19:30.748212: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
```

Note that I am using the pretrained model obtained from the instructions using this command:

> wget -O -
>   https://github.com/mozilla/DeepSpeech/releases/download/v0.3.0/deepspeech-0.3.0-models.tar.gz
>   | tar xvfz -

Where is the Tensorflow v1.11.0 coming from? pip freeze shows Tensorflow as v0.12.0? How do I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

Just a side note: it seems like the current version of `deepspeech` on `pypi` uses `tensorflow == 1.11.0`. I did not inspected the `*.whl` packages, but the upload date [here](https://pypi.org/project/deepspeech/#files) indicates that the package was uploaded on Oct 23, while DeepSpeech migrated to `tensorflow == 1.12.0rc2` on a later date (Oct 31) in [this commit](https://github.com/mozilla/DeepSpeech/commit/26f7bc30f03c424cb918e53dd9decc7a8c81991b#diff-b4ef698db8ca845e5845c4618278f29a).

Now, here is the list of things for you to check:

- Make sure that you're using pip **inside** the environment, i.e. make sure to do a `source activate env-name` first.
- Make sure as well that DeepSpeech is installed in the same environment. Keep in mind that your Anaconda Environment can still use packages from default Python of your system (in case you're using linux).
- If the above doesn't work, try [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269795/how-do-i-find-the-location-of-python-module-sources). Print out the path of TensorFlow library from your script (that says it is `1.11.0`, and from the place where you invoke `pip freeze` (i.e. from the terminal).