# Where can I find the wifite code directory?

Tags: python, directory, wifi, kali-linux, wep

I'm having the error "airplay-ng exited unexpectedly" when running an WEP attack with Wifite. In order to fix the issue i need to direct to the wifite code, which is by one sources saying, located in /usr/bin/wifite.

For my situation this is false. there is no wifite file located in that directory. There is how ever a Wifite file located in the /usr/sbin/ directory but the file only contains the following text:

`!/usr/bin/python3`

`from wifite import main__`

`main__.entry_point()`

It should be noted I am extremely new to linux, but my main question is how do i located the Wifite code? Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find the location of Python module sources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269795/how-do-i-find-the-location-of-python-module-sources)

Answer (score 0):

Wifite might be installed on your device as an application that has already been compiled, you might need to re install it using pip and re-checking the python packages.

Here is the GitHub Link:
https://github.com/derv82/wifite2