# Can I have same functionality as re.findall() without using any module directly in python?

Tags: python, nlp, python-re, autocorrect

My task is to use automata theory for autocorrect text. All my references show the use of re.findall() for the purpose of finding matches. Can I recreate the functionality without using any library directly. I am allowed to use different function form different libraries.

I am expecting something like source code for findall() function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find the location of Python module sources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269795/how-do-i-find-the-location-of-python-module-sources)

Answer (score 0):

CPython is open source. The sourcecode for the re package is [on github](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/main/Lib/re).